# Passing matrix to function handle (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab

If I have a set of functions

`f = @(x1,x2) ([x1 + x2; x1^2 + x2^2])`

and I have a second matrix with

`b = [x1,x2]`

How do I evaluate `f([b])`? The only way I know how is to say `f(b(1),b(2))` but I can't figure out how to automate that because the amount of variables could be up to n. I'm also wondering if there is a better way than going individually and plugging those in.

Comment: What is it that you wish to evaluate?

Comment: I need to get out what the f matrix is with x1, x2. Sorry wasn't clear, I'll edit the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

convertToAcceptArray.m:

```
function f = convertToAcceptArray(old_f)
    function r = new_f(X)
        X = num2cell(X);
        r = old_f(X{:});
    end
    f = @new_f
end
```

usage.m:

```
f = @(x1,x2) ([x1 + x2; x1^2 + x2^2])
f2 = convertToAcceptArray(f);
f2([1 5])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could rewrite your functions to take a vector as an input.

```
f = @(b)[b(1) + b(2); b(1)^2 + b(2)^2]
```

Then with, e.g., `b=[2 3]` the call `f(b)` gives `[2+3; 2^2+3^2]=[5; 13]`.

Comment: Matrix subscripts inside brackets is not valid syntax in MATLAB. Also, how does redefining `f` like this help?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `b` is an N-by-2 matrix, you can invoke `f` for every pair of values in `b` as follows:

```
cell2mat(arrayfun(f, b(:, 1), b(:, 2), 'UniformOutput', 0)')'
```

The result would also be an N-by-2 matrix.

Alternatively, if you are allowed to modify `f`, you can redefine it to accept a vector as input so that you can obtain the entire result by simply calling `f(b)`:

```
f = @(x)[sum(x, 2), sum(x .^ 2, 2)]
```